# Arrow keypress not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This are my code hope any kind souls will be kind enough to help me.
Other Keys like Alphabets or Home or PgUp etc.. is working. Except for all the arrows.

```
void AutoMove (HWND hWnd)
{
 BOOL bWorked = FALSE;
 int value = 0;
 LPARAM lparam = (MapVirtualKey(0x025, 0) << 16) + 1; //Send to graphic screen
 HWND MSHWND = FindWindow ("MapleStoryClass",0); //Find class window

 value = GetDlgItemInt(hWnd, IDC_GETAUTOMOVE, &bWorked, 0);
 SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_AUTOMOVE, "On" ); //"On" message

 while (!AutoMoveExit)
 {
  PM(MSHWND, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x025, lparam); //Send Left Arrow Key
  Sleep (1000);
  PM(MSHWND, WM_KEYUP, 0x025, NULL);
  Sleep (value);
 }

 SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_AUTOMOVE, "Off" ); //"Off" Message
}
```

Comment: Anybody using macros like this should be shot, no questions asked.

Comment: @Hans: be nice, he's new around here. Probably didn't even write the macros himself. (Though why someone would bother writing a macro just to shorten PostMessage to PM escapes me.)

Comment: @egrunin - I wasn't picky about the target :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested yet, but you can try ignoring the `lParam` value like this:

```
PostMessage(MSHWND, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_LEFT, 0)
```